# Why doesnt my computer boot when I have my USB bluetooth plugged in?

Tags: windows-7, usb, boot, bios, bluetooth

I have a USB bluetooth dongle that I got from best buy a few years back. I kept it plugged in to my laptop and it used to boot fine. Now about a week ago, I  got a new laptop and I cant leave it plugged in or the computer wont boot. I tried to see where exactly was causing the error, but it happened in multiple places. If I have it pluged in when I turn on my computer, it wont get past post. Once it passes post if I plug it in, it freezes on the windows 7 loading screen. then if I plug it in past that, the windows 7 welcome screen freezes. Why is this happening and is there anything I can do to prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

Its possible the new computer BIOS is set to boot from USB before internal disk.  Old PC may have been different.  Check out your BIOS setings.

Comment: nope, ive checked. USB is one of the last things it boots from

Comment: I know this is old, but I have similar problem with desktop and usb flash drive.   but in my case it only freezes the boot screen and NO the boot sequence is not set to boot from usb.

Answer (score 0):

Does the device still work with other computers? it may have become damaged somehow.

It's possible you've discovered some sort of incompatibility between your BIOS and the USB controller in the bluetooth dongle that's locking up the BIOS when it tries to interact with it for boot-from-USB purposes. This seems fairly unlilkely, though.

Answer (score 0):

Your new laptop may already have a built-in bluetooth (as almost ALL new laptops have it!) and they may be conflicting each other.

Comment: it doesn't, and wouldn't i see any sort of conflict after boot if that were the case?